# How can I change border's color independent of it's width and shape in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How can I change composable's border's color, width and shape independently instead of having to pass all 3 properties in one function i.e. `Modifier.border()`

I have one simple use case where a 3rd party composable has some kind of border, let's say `Red` color, `2.dp` width and `Rectangle` shape. Now I only want to change that border's color to `Blue` but don't mess up with the width and shape, how can I achieve this?

It would be nice to also have `Modifer.borderColor()`, `Modifier.borderWidth()` and `Modifier.borderShape()` extension function along side `Modifier.border()`. What would be it's implementation and how can I achieve this on my own?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension function with default parameters

```
fun Modifier.border(
    width: Dp = 2.dp,
    color: Color = Color.Red,
    shape: Shape = RectangleShape
) = this.then(Modifier.border(width, color, shape))
```

Comment: But I don't know default values, the border already exists in the 3rd party composable. I just want to change one property without changing other two

Comment: You need to post how third party creates border. Also i don't think you can change existing border. Because border uses color, shape and, width parameters assigned not from theme or any local provider

Comment: You also need to check how this third party draws border. Is it via border, or drawWithContent or with Canvas. You can't just simply change behavior of any third party library without how it works

Comment: It uses Modifier.border() to add border

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change existing border. Because parameters come from user and there are no default params. If they were provided from theme or any local provider it would have been possible. What you propose as extension functions work when there is a way to provide values to Composables or Modifiers.

Comment: Yes, I can contact them. Can you show a little code snippet on how it can be done with `CompositionLocal` and `CompositionLocalProvider`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247670/discussion-between-thracian-and-danish-ansari).